Nginx: return 403 with custom error message (not error page)
I have a simple Nginx server block for a specific port that always returns 403 and I'm trying to return a custom error message with the response, without having to use a custom error page.
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:9999;
    server_name _;
    return 403 "My custom error message";
}

Testing this via curl returns the expected result, but when testing in web browsers (Chrome/Firefox/Opera) the page does not return anything.
What must I change for the web browser to show my custom error message?

You should add default_type text/plain;
server {
    listen 9999;
    default_type text/plain;
    return 403 "My custom error message";
}

Default content type in nginx is application/octet-stream and browsers usually don't show it.

Hi Alexey, thanks, this worked! I tried to set add_header Content-Type text/plain; before but that di NOT work.
